# Cacti Export Tool Script

Tags: centos, scripting, shell, cacti, export

I'm looking for any script that possible to export graph of Cacti into CSV/text format. 
I have several interfaces in different devices, so I want to export those graph by using cron's job for sending report of bandwidth utilization regularly.

Appreciate your help and input.

Regards,
SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cacti stores its data in `RRD` format.
[Use `rrdtool` to perform operations on the `RRD` files.](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)

Comment: Could you give me any example please?

Comment: @Sokphak No -- sorry but I'm not going to spend an hour remembering how `rrdtool` works and contriving an example for you. But you can read the documentation (which contains examples), or the resources in [the question Andrew refers you to](http://serverfault.com/questions/495652/how-to-export-munin-raw-data-to-csv), or any number of resources on Google. You will also learn far more doing your own research than having the answer handed to you.